# thumbs_up one highest liked picture (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, voting

I'm having problems with the [thumbs_up gem](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up).

Here is how my app works:

Pictures act as voteable, users act as voters. They can like and dislike pictures (so the plusminus count can go negative, too). In the pictures database: user_id, `:name`, `:image`, `:fame`. Fame is a boolean and is by default false.

And here is what I want to do now:

Every 24 hours the picture with the highest plusminus tally gets its `:fame` value changed from false to true, thereby disappearing from the picture library (pictures#index) and appearing on pictures#highest. Only this one picture, changing every 24 hours.

Basically I don't know how to change the boolean of the most liked picture to true every 24 hours, and how to select the picture with the most likes. Any code is appreciated.

Comment: you should change your question to include what is wrong with your code.

Comment: I don't know how to do the thing I wanna do (changing pic every 24h), just pasted the code in case it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the `thumbs_up` gem.

Your problem is that you don't know how to schedule periodic tasks.

A tool that you can use for this is the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). It lets you do stuff like this:

```
# in whenever
every 24.hours do
  rake "pictures:set_fame"
end

# lib/tasks/my_task.rake
namespace :pictures do
  task :set_fame => :environment do
    # N.B.: I haven't had the chance to test this query.
    Picture.where(fame: true).first.update_attribute(:fame, false)
    Picture.order('tally DESC').first.update_attribute(:fame, true)
  end
end
```

Comment: so I did this:
`#schedule 
every 2.minutes do
  rake "pictures:set_fame"
end
`

and

`#set_fame.rake 
namespace :pictures do
  task :set_fame => :environment do
    Picture.where(fame: true).update_attribute(:fame, false)
    Picture.order('plusminus_tally DESC').first.update_attribute(:fame, true)
  end
end`

and it doesn't update. where am I wrong? and thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm really not sure about how to write the query for the most popular Picture, and I can't test it right now. So that can be a potential problem.

Comment: rake aborted!
undefined method `update_attribute' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe6420dfc48>
/Users/XXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'
/Users/XXXX/rp/XXXX/lib/tasks/set_fame.rake:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => pictures:set_fame
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

perhaps this error helps? :)

Comment: You should begin by testing the query from `rails console`, than test the rake task by running it manually. After that start troubleshooting whenever.

Comment: Just realized I had an error: `Picture.where(fame: true)` should be `Picture.where(fame: true).first`. See my edit!

Comment: now the error is Could not find table 'pictures' . The "fame" is a migration btw, AddFameToPictures, so perhaps it has something to do with that

Comment: This means that the pictures table doesn't exists. You probably haven't run you migrations. Run `rake dg:migrate`.

Comment: it exists, and everything about the table works (shows pictures, etc.). It displays them, except the boolean doesn't change.

Comment: The problem could be due to the rake task being executed in the wrong environment, i.e. you have the db set up for development but the task is executed in production

Comment: now the error is, again, undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Okay so the query has failed. For the first query, you may need to first check that there actually is a Picture with fame=true

Comment: this is what happens now:
if there is one picture that is set to true, the error is Could not find table 'pictures' (the environment is set to development). after 2 minutes the true one becomes false, and no picture becomes true. the error then is: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: plusminus_tally: SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures"  ORDER BY plusminus_tally DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: That means that the query is wrong and that you need to look at the documentation for `thumbs_up` to understand how to do the query.

Comment: it says this in the ducumentation: @items = Item.plusminus_tally.limit(10).where('created_at > ?', 2.days.ago).having('plusminus_tally > 10')
so I really don't get what's wrong :)

Comment: Dude, that looks nothing like the code that you said you were executing. It's close to impossible to figure out what you're doing wrong when the information you're providing is so out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

to change the boolean value do

```
@pic.update_attribute(:fame, true)
```

for every 24 hours try using the `whenever` gem

https://github.com/javan/whenever

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

to select picture with most votes try this

```
@best_pic = Picture.all.sort{|a,b| b.votes.count <=> a.votes.count}.first
```